# jQuery remove error label from HTML block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have an error label be removed from my html when the field content is changed. It works fine on `input` and `select`, but not in `input-group`. I want one command that will works on all instances of HTML.

I have a [JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/w04t3scv/) of my issue.

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control error-input" id="cc-exp_month" name="cc-exp_month" autocomplete="cc-exp_month" required="">
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <label class="error-message">This expiry date is invalid</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control cc-name  error-input" placeholder="Card Name" name="cc-name" id="cc-name" autocomplete="cc-name" required="">
    <label class="error-message">This card is invalid</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control cc-cvv error-input" placeholder="•••" maxlength="4" name="cc-cvv" id="cc-cvv" autocomplete="off" required="" data-numeric="">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <a href="#" id="cvv-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="" data-placement="top" data-original-title="CVV">
                                <i class="icon-help ion-fw"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
    </div>
    <label class="error-message">Invalid cvv</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS to remove error class and label on change:

```
$('#cc-exp_month').change(function() {
  $('#cc-exp_month').removeClass('error-input');
  $('#cc-exp_month').parent('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
});

$('#cc-name').change(function() {
  $('#cc-name').removeClass('error-input');
  $('#cc-name').parent('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
});

$('#cc-cvv').change(function() {
  $('#cc-cvv').removeClass('error-input');
  $('#cc-cvv').parent('.form-group').next('.error-message').remove();
});
```

the CVV field looses its class but I cannot delete the error lable below. I am looking to achieve a "generic" jquery chained command that can work on both instances (input and input-group).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w04t3scv/20/)**

```
$('input').change(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('error-input');
  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
});

$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('error-input');
  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your html the closest parent of `.cc-cvv` is `.input-group` and not `.form-group`. 
Try changing

```
$('#cc-cvv').parent('.form-group').next('.error-message').remove()
```

to

```
$('#cc-cvv').parent('.input-group').next('.error-message').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use change event on input tag
use keyup or keydown event for inputbox :

```
$('#cc-name').keydown(function() {
  $('#cc-name').removeClass('error-input');
  $('#cc-name').parent('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

```
$("div.form-group").on("change", function() {
    var div = $(this);
    div.find(".error-input").removeClass("error-input");
    div.find("label.error-message").remove();
})
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj2krL8f/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to achieve this, and use `$(this)` to select the chained selectors.

**E.g.**

```
$(function() {
  $('#cc-exp_month, #cc-name, #cc-cvv').on('change', function() {
    // Do whatever validation you need..

    $(this).removeClass('error-input');
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
  });
});
```

**Here's your snippet.**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cc-exp_month, #cc-name, #cc-cvv').on('change', function() {
    // Do whatever validation you need..
    
    $(this).removeClass('error-input');
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('label.error-message').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.error-message {
  color: red;
}

.error-input {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control error-input" id="cc-exp_month" name="cc-exp_month" autocomplete="cc-exp_month" required="">
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <label class="error-message">This expiry date is invalid</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control cc-name  error-input" placeholder="Card Name" name="cc-name" id="cc-name" autocomplete="cc-name" required="">
    <label class="error-message">This card is invalid</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control cc-cvv error-input" placeholder="•••" maxlength="4" name="cc-cvv" id="cc-cvv" autocomplete="off" required="" data-numeric="">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <a href="#" id="cvv-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="" data-placement="top" data-original-title="CVV">
          <i class="icon-help ion-fw"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <label class="error-message">Invalid cvv</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code.

```js
$("div.form-group").on("change", function() {
    var div = $(this);
    if(div.find('input').val() != ""){
      div.find(".error-input").removeClass("error-input");
      div.find("label.error-message").hide();
    }else{
      div.find("input").addClass("error-input");
      div.find("label.error-message").show();
    }
})
```